# Jquery validation directly inside Form Element setup?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, validation

Is it possible to have a jquery validation code on a form element directly inside the form element?

Example, say I have a textbox... Could I set it up like this...

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" validation="Here is where you place Jquery Validation Code that would execute onSubit of form">
```

I thought I saw that online some where while I was searching for something else... It would be great if you could do that, because it would really be what I need... Unfortunately, life is never so sweet...

But say you were generating your form elements on the fly, and you wanted each individual element to have a slightly different validation code to be run by jquery that would give you a false or a true if not met... 
How would you manage to do that?

Thanks,
Derek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know about doing it like that but have you looked at this plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ ?

Basicly, if you would have HTML like this:

```
<p>
<label for="firstname">Firstname</label>
<input id="firstname" name="firstname" />
</p>
```

And the form this is in has id signupForm, you would just do this:

```
$("#signupForm").validate({
    rules: {
        firstname: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 2
        }
    },
    messages: {
        firstname: {
            required: "Please enter your firstname",
            minlength: "Your firstname must consist of at least 2 characters"
        }
    }
});
```

Edited example with 2 rules. See the plugin documentation for details.